# What advantage is there to a larger hot water tank with a lower FHR?

Tags: water-heater

[This Rheem spec sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/WebPartners/ProductDocuments/cc0e544d-f428-422b-9b70-3c9413e00b47.pdf) shows that their 40 gallon tanks have a higher first-hour rating than the 50 gallon: 86 compared to 78. If this is true, why do the 50-gallon ones exist? By what metric are they better?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. I had an initial guess as to why this might be, and in the process of convincing myself, ie testing whether the guess holds up under inspection, I discovered a curious thing.

The [Water Heating Basics](https://www.hot-water-heaters-reviews.com/water-heating-basics.html) page at hot-water-heaters-reviews.com explains that First Hour Delivery equals (tank capacity) * 0.7 + (recovery rate). When I tested the numbers on the Rheem data sheet I ran into a problem.

For the 50 gallon natural gas fuel heater they claim recovery of 42.4. The formula yields 50*0.7 + 42.4 = 77.4 and approximately matches the table's First Hour Delivery of 78.

But look at the line for the 40 gallon: they claim recovery at 40.4 and the formula yields 40*0.7 + 40.4 = 68.4. That's nowhere near the table's FHD of 86 -- but if somebody fat-fingers the data and transposes the digits, 68 becomes 86.

Could it be that the data sheet is mistaken?

Comment: Interesting observation.  In looking at a similar product spec sheet from another manufacturer (https://www.americanwaterheater.com/media/51767/nrgss00115.pdf) I see that the 50 gal tank performs better in the 1st hour than the 40 gal model which is what you would expect.

Comment: This is interesting, even the [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Performance-40-Gal-Tall-6-Year-40-000-BTU-Natural-Gas-Power-Vent-Tank-Water-Heater-XG40T06PV40U0/204318424) purchase page lists the wrong numbers.  If someone messed up, the mistake made it everywhere (still possible, just interesting).

Comment: That's fascinating. I've sent Rheem a support request about this.

Comment: @TomHammingI'd love to know what they have to say - follow up if you think about it.

Comment: Heh, looks like they fat-fingered both the natural gas and liquid propane numbers.

Comment: Technically the heater is capable of that. My math says 40,000 BTU (on the 40 gallon tank) will heat just over 53 gallons of water by 90 degrees F in an hour. To achieve the FHR of 86 they need to heat 48 additional gallons of water in that hour (above the actual of 38 in the tank), which means 90% efficiency...maybe it's possible to be clever with how incoming cold water is handled?

Assume for the sake of argument that their spec sheet is right. Is there still some way in which the 50 gallon tank is better?